# it is possible to use Ajax with facebook api

Tags: php, ajax, facebook-graph-api

I want to use `ajax` to call `php` page, where `php` page creates a facebook event using `facebook api`.

I tried it, but it didn't work , did i make something wrong or it is not allowed to use ajax with facebook api ?

Comment: Well it IS possible ; tell us more about your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work as long as you get the correct access for the user. Are you getting an error?